# Delete range not working - Google Sheets API - Swift

Tags: java, swift, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am working on a view controller where the user should delete a row of a sheet within a spreadsheet which is located in google drive.

Once the user has successfully logged in, a table view is displayed and the user can delete the row by swiping left on the appropriate cell. The code below shows the deletion process. When I trigger the process, the following error is displayed:

"Invalid requests[0].deleteRange: No grid with id: 0"

```
    //Delete Function TableView - Access by swiping left.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    //1 - Delete Row From Index
    let toDelete = GTLRSheets_DeleteRangeRequest.init()
    toDelete.range?.sheetId = 317088521
    toDelete.range?.startRowIndex = 6
    toDelete.range?.endRowIndex = 6
    toDelete.range?.startColumnIndex = 0
    toDelete.range?.endColumnIndex = 3
    toDelete.shiftDimension = "ROWS"

    let batchUpdate = GTLRSheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest.init()
    let request = GTLRSheets_Request.init()
    request.deleteRange = toDelete
    batchUpdate.requests = [request]

    let deleteQuery = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsBatchUpdate.query(withObject: batchUpdate, spreadsheetId: spreadsheetID)
    service.executeQuery(deleteQuery, delegate: self, didFinish: #selector(deleteFromIndexWithTicket(ticket:finishedWithObject:error:)))
}

func deleteFromIndexWithTicket(ticket: GTLRServiceTicket, finishedWithObject result : GTLRSheets_BatchGetValuesResponse  , error : NSError?) {
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    print("Deleted from index")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad... I had not initialised the GridRange. Below is the working code.

```
        //1 - Delete Row From Index
    let toDelete = GTLRSheets_DeleteRangeRequest.init()
    let gridRange = GTLRSheets_GridRange.init()
    toDelete.range = gridRange
    gridRange.sheetId = indexID as NSNumber
    gridRange.startRowIndex = lengthTrainingDatabase - indexPath.row as NSNumber
    gridRange.endRowIndex = lengthTrainingDatabase - indexPath.row + 1 as NSNumber
    toDelete.shiftDimension = kGTLRSheets_DeleteRangeRequest_ShiftDimension_Rows
```